# How do I change a Variable, in a Java Class

Tags: java

I have to be able to convert some variables in my class. I have a boolean variable, WaGa (Stands for Workstation/Gaming computer), and if it's true, I want to convert String WorGam

I have to do this through service and support methods, and I keep trying, but I constenly fail. It just prints out what's in the driver. HELP.

```
public class Graphics
//instance data
{
    private int Ram; 
    private String Brand;
    private int Res;
    private int BiWi;
    private int BaCl;
    private boolean K4;
    private boolean WaGa;
    private String WorGam;

    //boolean WaGa,  boolean K4, int BaCl, int BiWi, int Res,  String Brand, int Ram


    public  Graphics (int R, String B, int Re, int Bi, int Ba, boolean K4, boolean Wa, String Wor )     // constructor
    {
        Ram = R;
        Brand = B;
        Res = Re;
        BiWi = Bi;
        BaCl = Ba;
        K4 = K4;
        WaGa = Wa;
        Wor = WorGam;
    }

    public int get_Ram() //Accessor Method - there are 3 of them
    {
        return Ram;
    }

    public String get_Brand() //Accessor Method - there are 3 of them
    {
        return Brand;
    }

    public int get_Res() //Accessor Method - there are 3 of them
    {
        return Res;
    }

    public int get_BiWi() //Accessor Method - there are 3 of them
    {
        return BiWi;
    }

    public int get_BaCl()
    {
        return BaCl;
    }

    public boolean get_K4()
    {
        return K4;
    }

    public String WorGam(boolean WaGa)
    {
        String WorGam;
        if ( WaGa == true) {
             return WorGam = "Workstation";
        } else {
            return WorGam = "True";
        }
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return ("Ram" + " " + Ram + ". " + "Brand:" + " " + Brand + ". " + "Resolution" + " " + Res + ". " + "Processer" + " " + BiWi + "." + " " + "Base Clock" + " " + BaCl+ " " + "K4?" + " " + K4+ " " +WorGam);
    }
}

public class Graphicse_Driver
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
{

Graphics unique=new Graphics(4, "Nvinda", 6, 7, 9, false, false, "sdf"  );

System.out.println(unique);
```

Comment: I honestly don’t know what you’re asking.  What does “change a variable” mean?  What does “convert some variables” mean?  What are “service and support methods”?  Describe what “fail” means—what did you expect to see, and what did you see instead?

Comment: I want to print WorGam, and if WaGa's true, then WorGam prints "Workstation" and if false, it prints "Gaming"

Comment: Sounds like an if statement. And you really should use proper variable and method naming conventions.

Comment: I did, however, WorGam refuses to print out what I return in WorGam method. It only prints what I had as a placeholder in the driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to reread you code to make sure there aren't any other mistakes in your code, but this is the root of your problem.

In order to access the `WarGam` getter, you need to call:

```
System.out.println(unique.WarGam());
```

When you do `System.out.println(unique)`, you are trying to print out the entire `Graphics` object instead of just the `WarGam` string.

You then should change your `WarGam()` method to look like the following:

```
public String WorGam()
{
    if (WaGa) {
        return "Workstation";
    }

   return "Gaming";
}
```

Here is a more in depth explanation of the changes:

1. `WaGa` is a private variable of your `Graphics` class. Since the `WarGam()` method is in the same `Graphics` class, it already had access to the `WaGa` variable, so you do not need to pass it in.
2. `if(WaGa == true)` is just a wordier way of writing `if(WaGa)`.
3. Instead of creating a `String WorGam` variable, you can just return the string you want directly.
4. The `else` surrounding the second `return` is unnessary since that code will only be hit if the first `return` is skipped.

After these changes, the `private String WarGam` variable is really not necessary either.

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct your `worGam()` function:

```
public String worGam(boolean waGa) {
    if (waGa == true) 
        return "Workstation";
    else
        return "True";
}
```

And the `main()` function:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {

    Graphics unique = new Graphics(4, "Nnn", 6, 7, 9, false, false, "xxx");

    System.out.println(unique.WorGam(false));
}
```

Comment: Still prints the same thing, unfountly. I need it to print ether workstation, or true, but it keeps printing the placeholder i had, whether i used you're answer or not.

Comment: @ZachArmstrong So you need to modify the main() function. Check my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String worGam(boolean waGa) {
    if (waGa) 
        return "Workstation";
    else
        return "Gaming";
}
```